# Trying to attempt the readability problem in cs50. Unable to count the letters in a string

Tags: c, cs50

Why is my code not working. I have already spent 3 days on this and am looking for some help. I want to print the number of letters in the string but it keeps throwing a random number as the output. My code is as follows:

```
#include <cs50.h> #include <stdio.h> #include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
//Prompt the user for Text
string Text = get_string("Text: ");

//Count the number of lowercase and uppercase letters in the Text
int n = strlen(Text);
int array[n];
int L = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  L += array[i];
}
printf("%i letter(s)\n", L);
}
```

Comment: You should revise your cs50 lectures :-)

Comment: Please `#include <ctype.h>` and use `islower()` and `isupper()`. So `if(islower(Text[i])) { L++; }`

Comment: You assert that your code isn't working, but what actually is the desired output? Judging from the comment in your code, the # of upper/lowercase chars in `Text`? If so, then there is no need for `array` (and for VLAs in general, for that matter)

Comment: @vmt is right, you should provide some example of what the expected outputs are given some inputs

Comment: It's outputting random numbers because you are currently summing the values stored in the variables called "array". That variable is not initialized, so every time you run your program it will contain different values.

Comment: @vmt so given the following input - 'My name' I want the output to show: 6 letter(s).

Comment: @fstamour you are correct I was not initializing it.

Comment: Why don't you debug it by putting a breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Check this approach

```
//Prompt the user for Text
string Text = get_string("Text: ");

//Count the number of lowercase and uppercase letters in the Text
int lo = 0; up = 0;

for (int i = 0; text[i] != `\0`; i++) {
  
    if( text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z' ) {
        ++lo;
    }
    else if( text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z' ) {
        ++up;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should result in an infinite loop, what does `string != '\0'` is supposed to mean?

Comment: @Davide why have you taken it as string[i] and not Text[i] ?

Comment: We have definited Text as the variable where the sentences will be stored so shouldn't Text be an array of characters?

Comment: Thank you guys! I was able to solve the problem! Love this platform already. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes you are right, it should have been text[i]

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
{
//Prompt the user for Text
string text = get_string("Text: ");

//Count the number of lowercase and uppercase letters in the Text
int n = strlen(text);
int Letters = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  if (isalpha(text[i]) != 0)
  {
  Letters++;
  }
}
printf("%i letter(s)\n", Letters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IDK if is the best design but for me work it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    int counter_letters = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            counter_letters++;
        }
    }
    printf("%i letter(s)\n", counter_letters);
}
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this approach over the code offered by the existing two answers?

Comment: I am new in programming and i think my code "cleaner". Just it is lol.

Comment: and is very simple to understand THE CODE.

Comment: The purpose of my question is to encourage you to offer an explanation. Your code is easy enough to understand in isolation. But when a reader with a similar problem sees multiple responses with large blocks of code, it can be daunting to sort through them. As such, we encourage contributors to provide some explanation that helps readers get a sense of what's different, or highlight the key elements, when posting answers.